# Bootstrap 3 modal in navbar not link not clickable in ios

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this site: http://acmekitchensd.com there is a modal that shows a reservation widget. In iOS if you click the link "reserve" in the navbar the modal doesn't work.  But if you click the link on the home page that says "Reservations" the modal does work.

How can I make the navbar link to the modal, "reserve," work in iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Missing the href="#" which is needed for iOS.

In your menu, change:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

to:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```